# How to correctly delete an object from an array by name?

Tags: javascript

How do I delete the created object "bird" from an array by name ie by the keyword "bird"?

```js
var storage = [
    {cat: {name: "Garfild", count: 3443, price: 1000}}
];

function addProduct(newProduct) {
    storage.push(newProduct);
}

addProduct({dog: {name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000}});
addProduct({bird: {name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000}});

function deleteProductByName(productName) {
    storage.remove(productName);
}
deleteProductByName("bird");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate from the end of the array and splice the found item, which uses a check if the property exists in the object.

```js
function addProduct(newProduct) {
    storage.push(newProduct);
}

function deleteProductByName(productName) {
    var i = storage.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (productName in storage[i]) {
            storage.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

var storage = [{ cat: { name: "Garfild", count: 3443, price: 1000 } }];

addProduct({ dog: { name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000 } });
addProduct({ bird: { name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000 } });

deleteProductByName("bird");
console.log(storage);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You may do it like:

```
storage = storage.filter(item => Object.keys(item)[0] !== 'bird');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the remove like this if **filtering** is not what you want but really remove the data to the original array:

```js
var storage = [
    {cat: {name: "Garfild", count: 3443, price: 1000}}
];

function addProduct(newProduct) {
    storage.push(newProduct);
}

addProduct({dog: {name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000}});
addProduct({bird: {name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000}});

function deleteProductByName(productName) {
    var index=storage.map(function(e) { return Object.keys(e).join(); }).indexOf(productName);
   storage.splice(index,1)
}
deleteProductByName("bird");

console.log(storage)
```

It does the job. But I propose some refactoring. If you want each function to be fully testable, you should inject the parameters in and avoid global variables, give the dependence to the code that is using it. Make your functions no longer concern with some details. So you can have something like:

```js
var storage = [
    {cat: {name: "Garfild", count: 3443, price: 1000}}
];

function addProduct(newProduct) {
     return function(storageArr) {
             storageArr.push(newProduct);
             return storageArr;
       }
}

storage=addProduct({dog: {name: "Rex", count: 1488, price: 2000}})(storage);
storage=addProduct({bird: {name: "Eagle", count: 4042, price: 3000}})(storage);
console.log(storage);

function deleteProductByName(productName) {
    return function(storageArr) {
            var index=storageArr.map(function(e) { return Object.keys(e).join(); }).indexOf(productName);
            storageArr.splice(index,1);
            return storageArr;
        } 
}

storage=deleteProductByName("bird")(storage);
console.log(storage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your delete function, and return false or true based of whether the delete was succesful:

```
function deleteProductByName(productName) {
    var index = storage.indexOf(storage.filter(function(d,i){return Object.keys(d)[0] === productName})[0]);
       return !~index ? false : (storage.splice(index,1),true);
  }
```